# Issue with my prompt not working when adding new functions to my js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a very novice coder in html and js. I am trying to make a page that accepts a name from a prompt and then performs some animations with radio buttons. My prompt was running smoothly until I added the functions for radio button changes. Any help would be great!

when I comment out my code, the prompt works, any other code I add to my hw4.js file makes the prompt not work.The entire code itself involves AJAX and Cookies as well but I decided to hold off on that complexity until this is running well. I've also tried downloading JQuery or referencing it with different links online.

In HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Greeting Page </title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="hw4.js" defer></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head> 
<body> 
    <h1>A Greeting Page for Important People</h1>

    <section id= forms>
        <form id = "speedForm" class="forms">
            <p id = "speeds">
                Speed 0 <input type="radio" name=choice value="0" id= "speed0" checked> Speed 1 <input type="radio" name=choice value="1" id= "1" > Speed 2 <input type="radio" name=choice value="2" id= "2" > Speed 3 <input type="radio" name=choice value="3" id= "3" > Speed 4 <input type="radio" name=choice value="4" id= "4" > Speed 5 <input type="radio" name=choice value="5" id= "5" > Speed 6 <input type="radio" name=choice value="6" id= "6" > Speed 7 <input type="radio" name=choice value="7" id= "7" > Speed 8 <input type="radio" name=choice value="8" id= "8" > Speed 9 <input type="radio" name=choice value="9" id= "9" > Speed 10 <input type="radio" name=choice value="10" id= "10" > <br>
                Speed 11 <input type="radio" name=choice value="11" id= "11" > Speed 12 <input type="radio" name=choice value="12" id= "12" > Speed 13 <input type="radio" name=choice value="13" id= "13" > Speed 14 <input type="radio" name=choice value="14" id= "14" > Speed 15 <input type="radio" name=choice value="15" id= "15" > Speed 16 <input type="radio" name=choice value="16" id= "16" > Speed 17 <input type="radio" name=choice value="17" id= "17" > Speed 18 <input type="radio" name=choice value="18" id= "18" > Speed 19 <input type="radio" name=choice value="19" id= "19" > Speed 20 <input type="radio" name=choice value="20" id= "20" > <br>
            </p>
        </form>

        <form id= "colorForm" class= "forms">
            <p>
                red <input type="radio" name= "option" value="red" id= "red" checked> yellow <input type="radio" name=option value="yellow" id= "yellow" > blue <input type="radio" name=option value="blue" id= "blue" > 
            </p>

        </form>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div class= "box">
            Welcome
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
```

IN JS:

```
var userName = prompt("What's your name?", " ");

$(document).ready(function() {      


$radios.change(function() {
  let $checked = $radios.filter(function() {.   // when radio buttons are changed for speed, check which was pressed 
    return $(this).prop('checked');
    });

    let speed = $checked.val()* 100;            // set value of checked button (0-50) * 100 to the speed
    $( ".boxes" ).effect( "shake", {times: 100}, speed);    //creat a shake effect on the box div at the corresponding speed
});


});

//event listener for color 

$(document).ready(function() {      


$radios.change(function() {
  let $checked = $radios.filter(function() {.   // when radio buttons are changed for speed, check which was pressed and return that object as $checked var
    return $(this).prop('checked');
    });

    let color = $checked.val();             // set value of checked button (0-50) * 100 to the speed
    $( ".boxes" ).css("backgroundColor", color); //change color of box to corresponding radio button value (red, yellow, blue)


});

});
```

Comment: There are two places where you have `{.` which is invalid syntax.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed but still no progress

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors that I spot. 
1) the code contains excessive '.' after { as it was mentioned above.
2) variables $radios are not loaded or defined. As soon as the script doesn't have "use strict" the error might not be visible to console.
3)  doesn't have "" for id name and e.t.c

Here is a simpler working sample for radios with event delegation. 
There is no need to select all the radios to identify which one is checked. 
Hang a listener to a parent element and check two things 
 1) Is e.target an input type? 
 2) get Value of it.

I hope it will help you. It would be better to see GitHub like PRs where code could be easy comments with fix recommendations. Anyway, try the following solution.

```js
"use strcit";

function addRadios(amount){
   
    radios =  document.body.querySelector('.forms');

    for(var i=0; i < amount; i++){
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        var radio = document.createElement('input');
        radio.type = 'radio';
        radio.classList.add('choice');
        radio.setAttribute('name','choice');
        radio.setAttribute('value',i);
        radio.setAttribute('id',i);
        radios.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Speed '+i));
        radios.appendChild(radio);
    }
    radios.children[0].id = 'speed0';
    radios.children[0].checked = true;
};

$("#speedForm").click( function(e){
    
    if($(e.target).prev().is("input")){
        let speed = $(e.target).val() * 100;  
        alert(speed);
    }
});

addRadios(10);
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Greeting Page </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head> 
<body> 
  <h1>A Greeting Page for Important People</h1>

  <section id= forms>
      <div id = "speedForm" class="forms">
      </div>
  </section>

  <section>
      <div class= "box">
          Welcome
      </div>
  </section>
  
  <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
```